# How to keep only the coastlines on TIFF file (No ELEV)

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a PNG library (524 288 Tiles of 256 * 256px) which I georeferenced via gdal (`gdal_translate` & `gdalwarp` => FILE.tiff)

The sea is black (RGB 0, 0, 0) and the land is white (RGB 255, 255, 255).

I would like to keep only the "limit" between land and sea (= coastlines).

I saw that there is `gdal_contour` but it is always a question of an elevation (ELEV) that I do not have and therefore I do not know how to get these coastlines ...

gdalinfo returns me this structure for each TIFF

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: map_11_480_100.tiff
Size is 181, 313
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Web mapping and visualisation."],
        AREA["World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N."],
        BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
    ID["EPSG",3857]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-1252344.271424327744171,7331600.036586093716323)
Pixel Size = (215.927731168155702,-215.927731168155702)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-1252344.271, 7331600.037) ( 11d15' 0.00"W, 54d50'37.50"N)
Lower Left  (-1252344.271, 7264014.657) ( 11d15' 0.00"W, 54d29'33.52"N)
Upper Right (-1213261.352, 7331600.037) ( 10d53'56.08"W, 54d50'37.50"N)
Lower Right (-1213261.352, 7264014.657) ( 10d53'56.08"W, 54d29'33.52"N)
Center      (-1232802.812, 7297807.347) ( 11d 4'28.04"W, 54d40' 6.87"N)
Band 1 Block=181x45 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  NoData Value=255
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 255,255,255,255
    2: 0,0,0,255
       [...]
  255: 0,0,0,255
```

I have this :

[image]

and I would like to get this: (by photoshop)

[image]

Can you tell me the method?

Comment: Look at vectorize operations

Comment: Thanks, I did not have explore this possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a fictional image (projected in meters) with your same Pixel Size (215.927731168155702,-215.927731168155702). It looks similar to your images when it was loaded in QGIS.

[image]

Use Polygonize (raster to vector) QGIS Processing Tool for obtained each features image. In Toggle Editing mode, delete bottom feature to get something similar to this:

[image]

Afterward, use Polygons to lines QGIS Processing Tool for obtaining similar following result:

[image]

Finally, if you want these lines also rasterized, you can use Rasterize QGIS Processing Tool. I used parameters of following image.

[image]

It resulted as follows:

[image]